# How to include javascript file only once?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline

I am using `pace.js` library and its documentation says, that I need to include their JS/CSS file as early as possible. http://github.hubspot.com/pace/ .  I did it and now my `application.html.erb` looks this way:

```
<head>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "pace.min" %>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag "pace", :media => "all" %>

  <title>My site</title>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", :media => "all" %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
</head>
```

But when I look at generated HTML I can see that pace is being included **twice**. 
First time at the begining of `<head>` and second time in place of `javascript_include_tag "application"`
How to prevent it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First time `pace.js` is included because of `<%= javascript_include_tag "pace.min" %>` statement where you have explicitly specified to include `pace.js` library.

And second time because of the following statement in `application.js`

`//= require_tree .`

This statement means that include all the `js` files in the current directory of `application.js`(`app/assets/javascripts`) and I am guessing that you have kept `pace.js` in the same directory which is why it is being included again.

**EDIT**

Use `stub` directive in `application.js`, if you want to exclude `pace.js` from the asset bundle and include it explicitly in `<head>`. This way `pace.js` would only be included once.

`//= stub pace`

Comment: If I simply allow Rails itself to include it (via //=require_tree .) then `pace.js` will be included as JS file #40, but to work properly pace.js library is required to be included at the top of <head> section

Answer (score 1):

There are also 2 gems setup for pacejs and rails

## 1

[pacejs_rails gem](https://github.com/guyisra/pacejs_rails)

## 2

[pace rails gem](https://github.com/drkyro/pace-rails)

alternatively, in your application.js file, list the order in which you need them

```
//= require pace
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require underscore
//= require backbone
//= require_tree .
```

where the tree will then grab everything else in order.

Pace would be included before the others listed